# how to calculate the confidence intervals for population mean when we have the standard deviation

Tags: statistics

Hi Experts i have the following R Script and i cannot understand why the upper and lower bands are different values for a 95& cofidence interval of 1.96

internet

```
num_rev <- 108
(incidence <- (num_rev/time_tot)*100)
(ci <- (unlist(prop.test(num_rev,time_tot)[6])*100))
```

correct results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say `time_tot` is 108 and your upper confidence interval can not be larger than 1, so all of the uncertainty has to be in the lower confidence interval.

```
time_tot <- 108
num_rev <- 108
(incidence <- (num_rev/time_tot)*100)
#[1] 100
(ci <- (unlist(prop.test(num_rev,time_tot)[6])*100))
#conf.int1 conf.int2 
# 95.71949 100.00000
```

See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16574/238346 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4713/238346.

In case you are exactly in the midle `(time_tot <- 108*2)` also the confidence intervalls are symetric

```
time_tot <- 108*2
num_rev <- 108
(incidence <- (num_rev/time_tot)*100)
#[1] 50
(ci <- (unlist(prop.test(num_rev,time_tot)[6])*100))
#conf.int1 conf.int2 
# 43.39058  56.60942
```